# Verify 2 web elements in table are equal or not

Tags: selenium

```
List<WebElement> tdata=driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> tdata1=driver1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for(int i=0,j=0; i<tdata.size() && j<tdata1.size();i++,j++  )
    {
        WebElement row  = tdata.get(i);
        WebElement row1  = tdata.get(j);
        System.out.print(row1.getText());
        System.out.print(row1);

        if(row.getText().equals(row1.getText()))
        {

            System.out.println(row.getText());

        }
      else if(!(row.getText().equals(row1.getText())))
        {
            System.out.print("Not matching text");
            System.out.println(row1.getText());

        }
    }
```

This is my code for comparing 2 web table, I am Unable to verify content equal or not equal. For unmatched text also it is not printing anything. else if part is not capturing if elements are not equal.

Comment: Can you please share HTML code behind it

Comment: List tdata=driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); List tdata1=driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
shows that tdata and tdata1 contain elements of same resource, hence when you compare, you are comparing the same element to itself.

Comment: thanks its tdata1 and tdata.

Comment: what is the difference between tdata and tdata1 ?

Comment: only single value is different in 1st row

Answer (score 0):

try

```
List<WebElement> tdata= ...
List<WebElement> tdata1= ...
int common= 0;
for (WebElement element: tdata) 
   if (tdata1.contains(element))
      common++;
```